# How to edit all word documents in a directory?

Tags: ms-word

I've been given the scut job of correcting some hundred or so code testing reports that have been filled out incorrectly by a senior coder who has more import work to do.

Unluckily for me all the files are ms-word documents. But luckily for the formatting is all the same and the errors are all made in the same cells in the same table.

In the past I wrote a bash to edit to change single quotes to double quotes on multiple xml files. But that was with a linux machine. This time around I have only a window machine.

Any hints where to begin?

Comment: Google "office interop"

Comment: You can use vba to do this

Comment: vba was the trick. Thanks @Sarkar Hasan

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use VBA. I built two subroutines.

The first subRoutine loops through the directory and
opens each *.doc file it finds. Then on the open document file it calls
the second subRoutine. After the second subRoutine is finished the document
is saved and then closed.

```
Sub DoVBRoutineNow()
Dim file
Dim path As String

path = "C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\myWorkFolder\"


file = Dir(path & "*.doc")
Do While file <> ""
Documents.Open FileName:=path & file

Call editCellsTableRow2

ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

~~~~~~

The second subRoutine only works if all documents have the same formating. 
For example: The second row of the only table in the document has cells numbered 6, 7, 8. These contain "dd/MM/yyyy" , "Last Name", "First Name"
These cells need to be changed to "yyyy/MM/dd", "Surname", "Given Name"

```
Sub editCellsTableRow2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, cel As Cell, i As Long, n As Long
With ActiveDocument
For Each Tbl In .Tables

Tbl.Rows(2).Alignment = xlCenter

For Each cel In Tbl.Rows(2).Cells

If cel.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
cel.Range.Text = vbCrLf + "yyyy/MM/dd"
End If

If cel.ColumnIndex = 7 Then
cel.Range.Text = vbCrLf + "Surname"
End If

If cel.ColumnIndex = 8 Then
cel.Range.Text = vbCrLf + "Given Name"
End If

Next cel
Next Tbl
End With
Set cel = Nothing: Set Tbl = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```